# Reding some lines of input in cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the following input:

1.first line is some natural number q;

2.next q lines are either '+' or '-' or 'insert'+space+somecharacter

the cin doesn't work here of course because of space so i tried to use getline in the following way:

```
int q;

cin>>q;

getchar();

while(q--){

    string s;

    getline(cin,s);

}
```

but in this way I can't read the first line and if I delete getchar Ican't read the last line.The problem is probably that the program reads an additional '\n'(Printing the input shows this).How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I wonder that why q lines ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to look for spaces, you may just read first thing, and if it's `insert` then you read once again:

```
int q;
cin>>q;
while(q--){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    if (s == "insert") {
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        // do something with s == "insert", c == 'h'
    } else {
        // do something with s == "+" or s == "-"
    }
}
```